# Integer Based Sensor Fusion/Kalman Filter

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, kalman-filter, sensor-fusion

Is anyone aware of a sensor fusion implementation that uses only integer operations instead of all the floating point accumulates/divides/multiplies in most open source implementations?

On my processor performing repeated floating point calculations are expensive and I want to reduce them as much as possible. I might lose some precision but my application does not require a highly precise output.

Is there any issue turning all the variables to ints and just taking the hit in precision? Any advice would be great, thanks all.

Comment: Try using fixed-point integer arithmetic, for example `1000` to represent `1.000`

Comment: What @WeatherVane said. Simply put - scale the quantities up a reasonable amount. Or use a dedicated Fixed Point library.

Comment: @WeatherVane : Fixed-point is a good solution, but you should use a binary-floating point representation for performance (i.e. your multiplier should be a power of 2 not a power of 10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of fixed-point is the best solution for flexible maths operations on a device with no FPU.

Anthony Williams' [fixed point maths library](https://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/news/optimizing-applications-with-fixed-point-arithmetic.html) would suit, it uses a 64 bit integer type to provide a 34Q28 (34 integer bits, 28 fractional bit) format floating point type with extensive maths, operator and conversion functions.  It is written in C++ to create a `fixed` type as a class, with extensive operator overloading and standard maths functions so that it is largely inter-changeable with `float` or `double` in existing code.

I realise the the question is tagged C but you need not use C++ syntax extensively, just compile your C code as C++, include the fixed.hpp header, replace `float` or `double` with `fixed` and compile/link the fixed.cpp file with your project.